# How I can loop these data using a formula in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following arrays:

```
m <- c(1, 4, 7)
n <- c(2, 5, 8)
p <- c(3, 6, 9)
A <- seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
```

My Formula is:

```
(A+m)*(exp(p+n))
```

I wnt to get the results for arrays. So m=1,n=2,p=3 for all possible A. m=4,n=5,p=6 for all possible A and m=7,n=8 and p=9 for all possible A. I want to use it when the numbers are increased in arrays.

The output is similar to this for the top and bottom three.

```
A   V1  V2  V3
-2  -148.41316  119748.3    120774764
-1.9    -133.57184  125735.7    123190259
-1.8    -118.73053  131723.1    125605754
-1.7    -103.88921  137710.5    128021250
-1.6    -89.0479    143697.9    130436745
-1.5    -74.20658   149685.4    132852240
…   ..  …   …
…   ..  ..  …
```

Comment: Try `crossing(A, m, n, p) %>% mutate(out = (A + m) * (exp(p + n))) %>% arrange(m, n, p)`

Comment: Thanks, does not give me the outcome. Also, I got an error for crossing functioning

Comment: It works fine for me.  Thanks for notifying

Comment: i.e. `crossing(A, m, n, p) %>% mutate(out = (A + m) * (exp(p + n))) %>% pull(out) %>% head#
[1]     -148.4132    -2980.9580   -59874.1417    -2980.9580   -59874.1417 -1202604.2842`  the order may be different because of the combinations

Comment: Sorry, it does not reflect my outcome. Based on these data we should have only four columns, i.e., A, V1, V2 and V3.

Comment: Yes, it is because I extracted the column out with `pull(out)` alone just to show the column values.

Comment: Can you show the calculation to get `-8646613.954    -3415828177`.  I tried with your numbers, it gives a different value `(-2 + 4) *(exp(6 + 5))#
[1] 119748.3
> (-2 + 7) *(exp(8 + 9))#
[1] 120774764`

Comment: (-2+1)*(exp(3+2))= -148.4132, and (-1.9+1)*(exp(3+2))... for V1

Comment: I am able to get that value if you check my previous output.  It is the value `-8646613.954` and `-3415828177`. How did you come up with that for `A = -2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(A)
for(i in seq_along(m)){
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(paste0("V",i)) := sapply(A, function(x){(x+m[i])*(exp(p[i]+n[i]))}))
}
```

Output

```
> head(df)
     A         V1       V2        V3
1 -2.0 -148.41316 119748.3 120774764
2 -1.9 -133.57184 125735.7 123190259
3 -1.8 -118.73053 131723.1 125605754
4 -1.7 -103.88921 137710.5 128021250
5 -1.6  -89.04790 143697.9 130436745
6 -1.5  -74.20658 149685.4 132852240
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is "...applys"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean running without sapply, lapply ...

Comment: You can use `purrr::map_dbl` instead of `sapply`, the syntax stays the same. You can also nest a second `for` loop: `for(j in 1:length(A)) {df[j,paste0("V",i)] <- (A[j]+m[i])*(exp(p[i]+n[i]))}`